# how to make discord emoji with hyperlink with python

Tags: python, emoji

I'm trying to make an emoji with click, but I don't know how to do it...

this is the code i am using:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
 
 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description="help") 
bot.remove_command("help") 
 
@bot.command()
async def emojibot(ctx): #Comando a decir
    await ctx.send('<:HabboHotel:1023577803817492490:https://habbo.es>') 
 
 
 
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("ready")
    
 
    
bot.run('')
```

This is the example I'm currently looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the message you are sending isn't an embed but is plain text, I believe this should work:

```py
async def emojibot(ctx): #Comando a decir
    await ctx.send('[:HabboHotel:](https://habbo.es)')
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work 

Comment: Would you mind telling me how it doesn't work? Does it throw an error right when the script is run? Does it throw an error when the command is run? Does it not produce any errors but sends a weird message? Does it not throw any errors and doesn't send any message at all?

Comment: That's how it shows
https://i.imgur.com/WQacycO.png